# C++ wrapper class for C# class calling a web service

Tags: c++, wcf, c++-cli, clr, wwsapi

So, I've written a web service in c#, which has a method for signing a hash. This web service is a WCF Service application.
Then, I've created a c# Console application where I've written a function to consume this web service.
The declaration of the function which calls the web service is that:

```
class Program
{
public byte[] callWS(string alias, byte[] myHash,string myPassword)
{
    IhashSignSVCClient client = new IhashSignSVCClient();
        byte[] signedData= client.SignandReturn(alias, myhash, myPassword);
        if (signedData != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(signedData);
            return signedData;
        }
        return null;

 }
}
```

This web service works fine. Now I want to build a c++ wrapper class over this c# method, because I want to call this web service from unmanaged code and I thought that creating a c++ wrapper class will be a good idea. Can anyone help me with a kind of a structure of this wrapper class? I haven't understood very well the conversions between c++ and c#. I've created a C++ CLR class library, with a ref class which will contain my c++ method to call this c# method, but I still have some problems with the type of parameters of this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to native (unmanaged) C++ (instead of using C++/CLI), your best option might be [WWSAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430435(v=vs.85).aspx) as that can call a WCF service directly from C++.  Although since it's a C-based API, it's a bit of a nuisance to use from C++.

Otherwise, there is extensive documentation about C++/CLI [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx); in particular [marshaling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't want to work with windows web services and I used to work with C++/CLI.